# error en eclipse c++?

Tags: c++

cuando creo un hello world me funciona pero si pego un bloque de codigo de otro sitio me sale ese error .

https://youtu.be/zu9DMuVC1ew

este es mi código:

```
 #include <iostream> #include <cstring> using namespace std; struct Node{ char *name; int age; Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){ name = new char[strlen(n) + 1]; strcpy(name, n); age = a; } }; Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1); cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age; strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy"); node2.name = 30; cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
```

y este el error en consola:

```
    20:13:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project gfr ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\gfr.o" "..\\src\\gfr.cpp" 
..\src\gfr.cpp:1:21: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
 #include <iostream> #include <cstring> using namespace std; struct Node{ char *name; int age; Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){ name = new char[strlen(n) + 1]; strcpy(name, n); age = a; } }; Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1); cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age; strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy"); node2.name = 30; cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
                     ^
g++ -o gfr.exe "src\\gfr.o" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

20:13:26 Build Finished (took 4s.313ms)
```

Comment: Jony agrega el código que produce error en tu pregunta por favor, y comenta que error se muestra en la consola.

Comment: En lugar de dejar un video mostrando el error deberías poner el código que no te está funcionando directamente en la pregunta.

Comment: Buen día Jony, he visto de donde tomaste este ejemplo, el libro se llama "Data Structures and Algorithms in C++
By Adam Drozdek" , trata de iniciar con lo básico de C++ por ejemplo este tutorial de explica lo básico para iniciar la estructura de un programa: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMJc8krx2n4 y trata de agregar el código la ocasion, no solo agregar un video.

Answer (score 4):

El error principalmente es que no esta indentado correctamente, si lo pones todo en una sola linea tomara una parte del codigo como  una directiva de preprocesador:

```
#include <iostream> #include <cstring> using namespace std; struct Node{ char *name; int age; Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){ name = new char[strlen(n) + 1]; strcpy(name, n); age = a; } }; Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1); cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age; strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy"); node2.name = 30; cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
```

debes indentar tu  código!

Tampoco tienes un main() definido, lo cual es sumamente importante!. Tu código correcto y bien formateado, debería ser similar a :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        age = a;
    }
};


int main() {
    Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1);
    cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
    strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy");
    node2.name = 30;
    cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
}
```

Comment: Y además también tiene un error en la linea `node2.name = 30;`, está tratando de asignar un `int` a un puntero de `char`.

Comment: En realidad son varios errores, el que me asusto mas es que no tiene main() =P jeje

Comment: *el que me asusto mas es que no tiene main()* jaja

Comment: @AngelAngel jaja Hola AngelAngel, de hecho he visto de donde obtuvo este ejemplo es de un libro llamado  "Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ By Adam Drozdek" lo puedes encontrar en google books, al parecer no es un libro para iniciarse en C++ no explica porque de las Preprocessor directives o porque un main()

Comment: @Elenasys probablemente sera eso, no me rio porque no pusiera el main, de echo siempre pienso cuando ocurren cosas asi que nadie nace sabiendo y "todos" en algun punto no sabiamos nada de nada, "aunque parece que con el tiempo la gente se olvida de muchas cosas a la vez que se hacen mas prepotentes... pero eso es otra historia jaja", me hizo gracia y de echo lo vuelvo a leer y me parece super graciosa la frase quizas algun dia aparezca como una cita quien sabe -> *el que me asusto mas es que no tiene main()* – Elenasys. jaja Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El código C++ compilable disponde de elementos finalizadores, a saber: `;` para finalizar cada instrucción y `}` para finalizar funciones, clases (en realidad éstas finalizan con `};`), espacios de nombre y ámbitos de ejecución. Debido a esta característica todo el código compilable de C++ se puede poner en una sola línea y sin espacios y el resultado compilará sin problemas.

Las directivas del preprocesador no disponen de finalizadores, por lo que al incluir una directiva en el código está tendrá vigencia hasta que finalice la línea en la que se encuentra dicha directiva. Debido a esta restricción únicamente se puede incluir una directiva por línea.

Con todo esto, el problema en tu caso es que estás mezclando directivas de preprocesador y código ejecutable en la misma línea y el resultado no es legal dentro del ámbito de C++.

Otro aspecto que te dará problemas es que el código ejecutable debe encontrarse necesariamente (salvo en el caso de variables globales) dentro de una función. Además todo ejecutable debe disponer de una función `main`. Tu no cumples ninguna de estas dos condiciones y el código, por mucho que lo separes en varias líneas, no compilará.

La solución más directa pasa entonces por aislar las directivas del preprocesador en líneas independientes e incluir el cuerpo del código en una función `main`:

```
// Directivas del preprocesador
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// Código compilable
using namespace std; struct Node{ char *name; int age; Node(char *n = "", int a = 0){ name = new char[strlen(n) + 1]; strcpy(name, n); age = a; } }; int main(){ Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1); cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age; strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy"); node2.name = 30; cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age; }
```

Aunque como te comentan en otras respuestas, lo más recomendable es estructurar el código en varias líneas y con indentaciones para que sea legible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
  char *name;
  int age;

  Node(char *n = "", int a = 0)
  {
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(name, n);
    age = a;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Node node1("Roger", 20), node2(node1);
  cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
  strcpy(node2.name, "Wendy");
  node2.name = 30;
  cout << node1.name << ' ' << node1.age << ' ' << node2.name << ' ' << node2.age;
}
```